# Tuning MySql on Solaris?

Tags: mysql, solaris

We are running MySql 5.x on Solaris 10.  Are there any good MySql options, or system options that we can use to optimize performance on an x86 Solaris 10 box with 16GB of RAM, running ZFS?  For example, with UFS, people recommended mount the filesystem with the directio option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using the MySQL from Sun's [Glassfish Web Stack](http://www.sun.com/software/webstack/features.xml) which is Sun's tuned version of MySQL for Solaris. Web Stack used to called [Cool Stack](http://cooltools.sunsource.net/coolstack/), and both are supported in [this forum](http://forums.sun.com/forum.jspa?forumID=980).

Answer (score 3):

Diet version:

ZFS:

- recordsize=16k
- logbias=throughput
- atime=off
- compression=lz4
- primarycache=metadata

InnoDB:

- innodb_doublewrite=0
- innodb_log_write_ahead_size=16384 (if your version has it)

There are a few other options you may want to look into. I wrote an article based on a talk I gave a while back about running
[MySQL on ZFS](https://shatteredsilicon.net/blog/2020/06/05/mysql-mariadb-innodb-on-zfs/) which you may find helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There is article about optimization of ZFS, but it's dedicated for InnoDB: [MySQL Innodb ZFS Best Practices](http://blogs.oracle.com/realneel/entry/mysql_innodb_zfs_best_practices)